# SqlDataReader - how to discover that column is empty

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqldatareader, is-empty

I try to read the result of the query and discover if some of the columns is empty
This is a way I started:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    rdr["ColumnName"]; // how do I know if it has a value or empty
}
```

I thought to do :

```
dr[4].ToString() == String.Empty
```

It makes a needed work, but I don`t like this (it is a hack rather than solution)
can you advise me how do I do it correctly and elegantly?

Comment: when you say "empty", does that include nulls? are you only concerned about var/char type columns?

Comment: @attila 1.NO 2.I am interested in int type columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty does not exists for int values and what is correct when working with databases is use **Null** which is the only true "Empty".

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int colIndex = read.GetOrdinal("MyColumnName");

while (rdr.Read())
{
    // [true | false] your validation goes here!; 

    if (rdr.IsDBNull(colIndex)){
       //value is  null
    }
}
```

Please note that if you want use 0, "" or 1/1/1900 as empty values those will require a custom treatment.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it

```
string UserInitialssql = rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? String.Empty : rdr.GetString(2);
```

If it is Int

```
Int32? i = rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? (Int32?)null : rdr2.GetInt32(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use nullable types. e.g.:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    int? someNumber = rdr["ColumnName"] as int?;
    if (someNumber == null)
        // was NULL in database
    else 
       // use  someNumber.Value   to get int
}
```